# Migration IIS7 site with SQL Server database to another server

Tags: sql-server, iis, msdeploy

I'm using MS Deploy as it's described [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/export-a-package-through-iis-manager) but I'm stuck with **dbFullSql** string format

```
Data Source=ISSUETRAK\ISSUETRAK_SERVER;Initial Catalog=Issuetrak;User Id=DOMAIN\Administrator;Password=*****;
```

and getting the following message

> Cannot connect to the database 'Issuetrak'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_DATABASE.
>   Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'data source=ISSUETRAK\ISSUETRAK_SERVER;initial catalog=Issuetrak;user id=DOMAIN\Administrator' cannot be created.
>   Failed to connect to server .
>   Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\Administrator'.
>   Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.
>   Failed to connect to server .
>   Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\Administrator'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to move Web Application using WebDeploy without database. And then I did backup SQL database backup on old server and restore on the new one. Hope that helps anyone.